# NUnit pass data from OneTimeSetUp to all tests in that fixture

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, nunit

In NUnit, I am attempting to initialize a variable during the test fixture's `OneTimeSetUp` and reference that variable in all test cases under that fixture.

The `OneTimeSetUpAttribute` is applied to a function in a file called `Initializer.cs`, where I initialize a new instance of a Selenium `IWebDriver` named `driver` and apply some common configuration options. My test cases are defined in `TestCases.cs` in the same namespace and directory as `Initializer.cs`. Is it possible to somehow pass the `driver` variable to the test cases defined in `TestCases.cs`? If not, then how should I address initializing a new instance of `IWebDriver` on each new test run without having to initialize it during the `SetUp` of each test case file I add? See the code below.

I am using Visual Studio Test Explorer to execute the tests.

**Initializer.cs**

```cs
namespace AutomatedTests
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class Initializer
    {
        IWebDriver driver = null;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Before()
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            // some initial browser configuration here

            driver = new ChromeDriver(".");
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void After()
        {
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**TestCases.cs**

```cs
namespace AutoamtedTests
{
    public class TestCases
    {
        [Test]
        public void AutomatedTest()
        {
            // is it possible to reference 'driver' here?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` attributes to accomplish this -- place your `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` methods in your `Initializer` class, above the `Before()` and `After()` methods respectively. Then, in your `TestCases` class, inherit `Initializer` so that you can access the `driver` class variable you declare & initialize there. Here's an example:

```
public class Initializer
{
    IWebDriver driver = null;

    [SetUp]
    public void Before()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        // some initial browser configuration here

        driver = new ChromeDriver(".");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void After()
    {
        driver.Close();
    }
}
```

Then, `TestCases.cs`:

```
public class TestCases : Initializer // inherit initializer here
{
    [Test] // each time you run this test, [SetUp] runs first
    public void AutomatedTest()
    {
        driver.FindElement(); // driver class variable inherited from Initializer.cs

        // you can use driver to initialize PageObjects too
        var myPageObject = new MyPageObject(driver); 
        myPageObject.DoSomething();

    } // each time this test is completed, [TearDown] runs
}
```

This easily gives us a way to utilize the PageObject model, too, because you can initialize PageObjects on the test-case level.

Comment: This is the safest approach, since each case has its own driver. If performancee problems arise, consider one driver per fixture but don't go beyond that!

Comment: The idea is to have a single driver instance that is created & destroyed for each test case run, so that every test case can run in an isolated context that is independent from other test cases. This also integrates well with parallel execution, because multiple test cases will not try to access the same driver instance.

Comment: Yes. I hope it was clear I was agreeing with your answer. :-)

Comment: Yep, just elaborating because I love creating clean test automation architecture :)

Answer (score 0):

Setup is meant to be executed once before each test,
OneTimeSetup, this is executed before
all the tests are run.
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-and-TearDown

This way, you have a single method. Or you could create an
initialization method, and run that in the beginning of each test.

Also, since the setup happens in the initializer, you should probably
let your testcases inherit from that initializer.
You also need a default constructor in your initializer.
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute

Another option, besides the inheritance, would be to make the driver
property static. Then you can just call it like

```
var _driver = Initializer.driver;
```

Comment: This answer contains several errors:
1. SetUp is executed repeatedl, once per test, while OneTimeSetUp is executed just once for a group of tests.
2. Inheritance would result in the OneTimeSetUp being executed once per test fixture. That's OK if that's what is wanted. In that case, make the class an abstract TestFixture rather than a SetUpFixture. 3. Static will only work if the driver is only created once. A common driver breaks in the face of parallelism.

Comment: @Charlie You are absolutely right about the 1st point, i'll change my answer.But why would static only work if the driver is only created once? you could just replace it whenever you like.

Comment: You would have to re-create it at a time when no other test is still using it. This is only possible in limited situations - i.e. no parallelism and no test corrupts the driver. Folks often start using static in a limited test case but then see things "mysteriously" breaking as it gets more complex.

Comment: that's a valid point, it would work fine if you run one test after the other, but running all tests simultaneously would indeed cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is not (and should not be) any connection between the `SetUpFixture` and the `TestFixture` it governs. As a result, there's no way to get the driver from the SetUpFixture except through a static property **which is just asking for trouble!**

In the case of a single fixture, the simplest thing to do is to create the driver in a `OneTimeSetUp` method within the fixture itself. In the case of multiple fixtures, you can repeat the same code or put it in a base class shared by all the fixtures. You will end up with one driver per fixture, which seems to be a good pattern for many web applications.

Note that you cannot share a fixture among tests that run in parallel. For parallel execution of test cases, you would have to initialize the driver in a `SetUp` method, so that each ase got it's own driver. The pattern I'm suggesting gives you a separate driver per fixture, so the fixtures can run in parallel while the test cases in each fixture should only run sequentially and should initialize the state of the driver as needed.